# Is it possible to extends only some part of the templates in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a blog app and in my about page I want to only extends navigation bar i don't want to extend sidebar which is present in my base templates. Is is possible to do, please explain. Because in my about page, I only want a images and some text with the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **include** feature of django HTML : `{% include 'app_name/template_name.html' %}`. Write the navigation bar and sidebar parts of html in two separate html templates.Then include one or both of them in other templates as you wish.
You can check out the documentation of **include** [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include).